# Writing G{\aa}rding

Tags: accents

Lars G{\aa}rding is a Swedish mathematician whom I want to quote. Although the macro `\aa` was usually providing the small circle above the `a`, it does not work with [`amsart`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add an example of failing code? Please, a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. Is the name in a bibliographic reference?

Comment: amsart does not change the definition of `\aa` note however you should use `G\aa rding` not  `G{\aa}rding` as the `{}` will, in general, interfere with hyphenation, or of course you can use `inputenc` package and enter it as Gårding

Comment: `\documentclass{amsart} \begin{document} G\aa rding \end{document}` works fine. Please provide an MWE.